# Generating A-Z, links that go to the same ClassBasedView and do a search

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-urls

I have a list from A-Z (alphabet) and when a user click one any of them I need to do a search.

I know, how to do the query:

```
 Post.objects.filter(name__istartswith='A')
```

Because I want to use just one CBV, I need an approach for:

1) generate the urls patterns in the Django template -> (string.string.ascii_uppercase)
2) how to get the letter from the url pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get letter using `self.kwargs` attribute of your view class (see related [part of doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)). Assuming your pattern is like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<letter>[a-z])/$', SomeView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Inside `SomeView` class you can override `get_queryset` method:

```
class SomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'users/user_post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(name__istartswith=self.kwargs['letter'])
```

Comment: @how do I generate the letters in the template, or do I need o set them manually ?

Comment: @user3541631 you can pass string `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` with template context. And use in template something like this: `{% for letter in letters %} <a href="{% url 'detail' letter=letter %}"> {% endfor %}`